# Endian representation of 64-bit values

Tags: c, 32bit-64bit, endianness

Suppose I have `unsigned long long x = 0x0123456789ABCDEF`.

Which of the following is correct? (I can verify only the first one):

- On a 32-bit little-endian processor, it will appear in memory as `67 45 23 01 EF CD AB 89`.
- On a 64-bit little-endian processor, it will appear in memory as `EF CD AB 89 67 45 23 01`.
- On a 32-bit big-endian processor, it will appear in memory as `01 23 45 67 89 AB CD EF`.
- On a 64-bit big-endian processor, it will appear in memory as `01 23 45 67 89 AB CD EF`.

Comment: have you tried? Have you googled that?

Comment: "Endian representation of a 64-bit **value**" would make a better title.  Registers on a 32-bit system are 32 bits.

Comment: @V-X: It didn't show up on stack overflow questions & answers. And as I mentioned in the question: I can only verify the first one (since I only have that specific processor at hand).

Comment: The second third and fourth ones are true, the first one is false. Note that 32 vs 64 bit is a red herring - only the endianness matters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first one is wrong. On ia32 at least the layout is `EF CD AB 89 67 45 23 01`.

The others are correct.

Comment: Thanks; I said "I can verify only the first one" but assumed I was correct, so didn't bother :) sorry ... My assumption was that "byte order" would apply on a variable with the size of no more than N bytes, where N is the processor's register-size. Apparently that assumption was wrong... thanks.

Comment: Please note that the answer to this question is not dictated by the C standard. The integer representation is up to the compiler manufacturer. It is permissible (although highly inconvenient) for a compiler to store integer values in a big-endian manner on little-endian hardware.

Answer (score 4):

Little endian means the least-significant bits are in the first byte, and big endian means the least-significant bits are in the last byte:

0x0123456789ABCDEF big endian is 0x01, 0x23, 0x45 ...

0x0123456789ABCDEF little endian is 0xEF, 0xCD, 0xAB ...

The native word endianess and size of the processor is inconsequential; the appearance in memory is dictated by the endian.

Comment: Yes, but it can only go up to a certain size. So if you have a structure with a size of 32 bytes, for example, it wouldn't "reverse all the bytes", correct? I've assumed that this size depends on the processor's register-size.

Comment: The endianness of an integer determines the byte order of that integer in memory.  Structures do not have endianness.  Endianness is a property of integers in a structure, but the structure itself is laid out as the compiler chooses, with the field alignment it chooses.

Comment: @barak manos There is [no size limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine). Sequential endian 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 and 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 are most common, but 5 6 7 8 1 2 3 4 and other variations exist.  For fun, note that a URL is a mixed endian "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21478765...".  If it was big endian, it would be "http://com.stackoverflow/questions/21478765..."

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the 32-bit solution is very much up to the compiler. It can choose to represent this type that it lacks native support for in any way it pleases, as long as the size is the expected one.

The 64-bit ones I'd agree with as being correct.