# Why the memory is interpretted differently on 2 different projects in same x64 machine ? Is that Endianness?

Tags: c++, windows, compiler-construction, 64-bit, endianness

I have a VS project in which I observe the **64 bit little-endianess** and in other test project it is something different [below memory layout and interpretation will give more info].
Both projects are compiled in x64 configuration

- Machine : x64- based PC
- Compiler: Visual Studio 2008

**MEMORY ==>  00 00 00 00 a0 f8  2c   00**

in one ->  it is interpretted as **0x00000000002cf8a0** correctly [not sure about the endian]

in other -> it is interpretted as **0x002cf8a000000000** [64 bit little endian]

Is there a compiler setting to force the Endianness ?

Comment: They don't have different endinanness. They're both little endian. The "bitness" (32/64) is not part of endianness.

Comment: @delhan from this link both 64 bit and 32 bit little endian differs right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21478765/endian-representation-of-64-bit-values

Comment: They don't, the OP made a mistake.  Read the accepted answer.

Comment: @HansPassant I am not sure about the endianess 64 bit or 32 bit little endianness. But I see different interpretations.Updated the question.

Comment: Its' "Indianness" :-)

Comment: There shouldn't be any circumstances under which `00 00 00 00 a0 f8 2c 00` is interpreted as a single integer `0x002cf8a0`.  Most likely this is actually a pointer to two four-byte integers, one of which is zero and the other `0x002cf8a0`.  (Of course, the software might be interpreting those two integers as the low and high parts of a larger integer, but that's got nothing to do with the compiler.)

Answer (score -1):

It depends on CPU, but do not forget that .Net uses virtual machine named CLR underneath.

Comment: If it is CPU, how does the 2 projects have different endianness even they compiled in x64 configuration ?

Comment: as delnan stated, endianness is not real issue here. Only bitness is different and AMD64 architecture has backward compatibility to x86.

Comment: if not endianess, what makes to behave differently in the memory interpretation for 2 different projects? "Only bitness is different and AMD64 architecture has backward compatibility to x86." both are  64 bit processes. can you elobarate your answer about difference in bitness ?