# Is Integer representation endian-depending?

Tags: integer, endianness, cpu-architecture, data-representation

[Tanenbaum says](https://www.tjhsst.edu/~rlatimer/arch/Chap2/Chap2B.html) that Integer is read "word by word" and thus,

[image]

obviously integers are stored the same way in BE and LE, while only strings are read "byte by byte".

However, Endianness describes how words are represented ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)), meaning different endianness = different storage of words. So why is it the same?

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21478765/endian-representation-of-64-bit-values) question, an `unsigned long long x = 0x0123456789ABCDEF` is stored differently:

```
01 23 45 67 89 AB CD EF // big endian vs
EF CD AB 89 67 45 23 01 // little endian
```

So what of that is true? Are integers (or numbers, for that matter) represented differently (byte by byte) or the same (altogether)?

Comment: "obviously integers are stored the same way in BE and LE" --> [Middle endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Middle-endian) gets no respect.

Comment: Post the relevant parts of "this question" here, rather than only link it to add clarity.

Comment: @chux ok I see. I tried rephrasing it a little.

Answer (score 1):

> Are integers (or numbers, for that matter) represented differently (byte by byte) or the same (altogether)?

C allows for a wide diversity of encodings - some are more common than others.  Yet all are constrained by some rules.

---

Take this in layers and use `signed int` for example.
In binary this would be `111...111000000001` wher ethe first `1` is the sign bit.

Layer 1: (Bit width `N`, value bits `M`) A "*signed* integer takes up N-bits.  With *signed* integers there is one sign bit and `M` value bits and 0 or more (rare) padding bits.  This totals `N`.  The order of these 3 groups and bits are not defined.  Instead operations like `>>`, `+`  are defined with an abstract numeric specification.  E.g. shifting left doubles the value.  The value of `M` greatly determine the range of `int`.

```
// common implementations.
int: N=32, M=31
int: N=16, M=15
```

Layer 2: (2's complement, sign/magnitude, or 1's complement) It it logical and universally implemented that the values bits are sequentially laid out starting with the least significant bit having value of 1 and the next bit has a value of 2, then 4, then 8, etc.  The *sign* bit in the overwhelming common 2's complement  layout has a value of -2<sup>M</sup>.  The other layouts are primarily of historic use.

```
// Common implementations include:
int: N=32, M=31, 2's complement
int: N=16, M=15, 2's complement
```

Layer 3: Byte width

An `int` takes up `N` bits, yet the numbers of bits/byte (the smallest addressable unit) is very commonly 8 bits/byte, but others exist, like 16, 64 and historically 9, 18, etc.  It must be at least 8.  For now, consider the near universal choice is 8 bits/byte.

```
// Common implementations include:
int: N=32, M=31, 2's complement, 4 bytes
int: N=16, M=15, 2's complement, 2 bytes
```

Layer 4: Endian.

With a typical `int` code over multiple bytes, does the lowest addressable byte  on the `int` encode the least significant bits or the greatest or something else?  The 2 most common are *little endian* and *big endian* as diagrammed by OP.  Other rare endians exist.

```
// Common implementations include:
int: N=32, M=31, 2's complement, 4 bytes, big endian
int: N=32, M=31, 2's complement, 4 bytes, little endian
int: N=16, M=15, 2's complement, 2 bytes, little endian
```

---

Example

With a value of -512, what is the value of the first byte?
As binary: `111...1110_00000001` with the first digit as the sign bit.

```
-511--> 0xFF (int: N=32, M=31, 2's complement, 4 bytes, big endian)
-511--> 0x01 (int: N=32, M=31, 2's complement, 4 bytes, little endian)
-511--> 0x01 (int: N=16, M=15, 2's complement, 2 bytes, little endian)
-511--> 0xFE (int: N=16, M=15, 2's complement, 2 bytes, big endian)
```

Answer (score 0):

> obviously integers are stored the same way in BE and LE

No they aren't; that's the whole point of endianness.  Yes each integer is stored in 4 bytes, but if you were to read that 4-byte word one byte at a time, you would see that little-endian puts the least-significant byte first, while big-endian puts the most-significant byte first in the representation of a single integer.

Look at the `long long` you included in the question for an example, and see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness.

---

Other endiannesses are possible, e.g. [PDP-endian actually exists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Middle-endian).  In theory any scrambling function for the bytes of an integer would be possible, but unless you're designing a Deathstation-9000, there's no reason to do anything weird.  (And definitely a reason *not* to do anything more weird than big or little endian, because it's nice if a 16-bit load of half of a 32-bit integer actually gets either the low or high half, not a mix of two other bytes.)

Comment: `"if you were to read that [integer] 4-byte word one byte at a time, you would see that little-endian puts the least-significant byte first"` - but what about the image in the question then? jim smith is reversed in LE, but the `21`  is on the far right in both LE and BE.

Comment: @Blauhirn: That's how the integer appears in a register after you load it; it's unscrambled.  If you look at the version of the tables in the link you posted, the columns are labeled `0 1 2 3` in the BE table, and `3 2 1 0` in the LE table.  So the string is actually stored in sequential order in both cases, but loading it word by word runs those bytes through the endianness scrambling of the CPU and produces that arrangement in a register (where left is the direction a left-shift goes; registers don't have endianness, just shifts).